# Disallow overlapping maximized window

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces

Tldr: I'd like to emulate macOS maximized window behavior:

- the maximized window fills the whole screen. Call this a maximized screen.
- no windows can be underneath the maximized window
- only modal dialogs from the same application can overlay the maximized window.

New and existing windows and dialogs get shoved to the neighboring unmaximized screen. There is always at least one such on macOS; also on ubuntu?

This is on ubuntu 21.10, tho I am happy to upgrade to a newer version if that resolves.

The behavior I am seeing is that only the "fills whole screen" bullet is satisfied.  Ubuntu is happy to over- and under-lap the maximized window.

I have tried with i3wm, and that is acceptable, but I would prefer a more targeted fix, if possible.

Comment: An extension like https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3100/maximize-to-empty-workspace/ may achieve something similar on Gnome Shell (default Ubuntu desktop)

Comment: @vanadium Would you mind making this comment an answer for visibility?

Comment: @user1717828 Yes, I did. It makes sense indeed because it comes close to the behavior the OP described.

Answer (score 1):

A behavior close to what you describe can be provided by the Gnome Shell extension [Maximize To Empty Workspace](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3100/maximize-to-empty-workspace/) by kaiseracm. As soon as you maximize a window, or create a new maximized window, it will be moved to an empty workspace created next to the current one. If you restore the maximized window to its normal state, it will be restored to the previous workspace.

A normal window can be underneath a maximized one, but that will only be so if you put it there yourself.